# Vue3: using curried function in composables not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, currying, vue-composition-api

I have a following composable:

```
export default function useReferralCodes(affiliateUserId) {
  let createReferralCode = (affiliateUserId, payload) => {
    console.log('affiliateUserId', affiliateUserId)
    console.log('payload', payload)
  }

  let curriedReferralCode = curry(createReferralCode)
  curriedReferralCode(affiliateUserId)

  return {
    createReferralCode,
    curriedReferralCode
  }
}
```

Now, when I use it inside component it is not working like so:

```
  methods: {
    onSubmit (payload) {
      this.curriedReferralCode(payload) // Outputs nothing
    }
  }
```

But this work:

```
this.curriedReferralCode(3)(payload)
```

Is there something I am missing or I really didn't exactly understand currying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the `curry` [api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curry), `curry` a function either calls the function if all its parameters are provided or returns a new function that requires only a subset of parameters if some are provided.

For example in your code

```
// createReferralCode requires 2 params
let createReferralCode = (affiliateUserId, payload) => {
  console.log('affiliateUserId', affiliateUserId)
  console.log('payload', payload)
}

// curriedReferralCode is the curried version of createReferralCode 
let curriedReferralCode = curry(createReferralCode)

curriedReferralCode(3, payload) // Equivalent to createReferralCode(3, payload)
curriedReferralCode(3) // Only 1 param provided out of 2: this creates and returns a function that requires the missing param *payload*
curriedReferralCode(3)(payload) // According to what has been said above, equivalent to createReferralCode(3, payload)
```

To fix your code:

```
// Provide the context param when you create the function
let curriedReferralCode = curry(createReferralCode)(affiliateUserId)
```

Comment: This work, but curry(createReferralCode)(affiliateUserId) calls the function. I intend to execute the function once the 2nd argument is provided.

Comment: im using lodash curry function.